# Is it correct to say “there was a long drive to <somewhere>”?

Tags: existentials

Is it correct to say “there was a long drive to <somewhere>”? or should I say “it was a long drive to <somewhere>”?

I googled this term and I found this sentence:
"Although it is a long drive to get to, arriving at Elephant sands was amazing." http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowUserReviews-g316100-d1447545-r87275381-Elephant_Sands_Botswana-Nata_Central_District.html

So I presume "it" is more common, but is using "there" wrong, noticing the fact that "there" means some thing exists? I read about "it" that it refers to time and weather. But does it also refer to distance?

Answer (score 1):

The "***there be***" phrases (with 'be' in the proper tense, person and number) *require* that "**where**" (to correspond to the "*there*") is either expressed or implied and not so hard to figure out.  The question you need to ask (and answer) is "***where* was** that long drive?"

When we say

> There will be hell to pay.

we imply *there* = *in the resulting conditions/circumstances*.  When we say

> There was a visit to Florida.

we imply *there* = *among other trips* during that summer.  When we start the story with

> There is this guy who keeps butting in on others' conversations.

we imply *there* = *among my acquaintances*.

So, in your story, is there a way for the reader to figure out *where* was that long drive?  If so, you're safe.  If *not really*, perhaps you should stick other constructs, like '***it***' as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Using there is just fine.

"To somewhere" works as a prepositional phrase that modifies "drive". Some similar examples are as follows.

> Trip to Italy made me so depressed.
>
> There was a visit to Florida.

But I think that "it" will be used more commonly as "there" makes this sentence a little unidiomatic to me.

Answer (score 0):

According to The Free Dictionary, you also use "it" as the impersonal subject of the verb "to be" to refer to time, distance, and the weather.

You normally say "It was a long drive to somewhere (say Paris)".